# Drupal goto not working correctly

Tags: 6, redirection, routes

I have a link `http://examplesite.com/my-site#userid`. Only authenticated users have permission to view this link. If unauthorized users follow this link I have created a redirect using `drupal_goto('another-page')`. But the unauthorized users are now being redirected to `http://examplesite.com/another-page#userid`. The `userid` part is not removed. Could someone help me with this.Thanks

When I go to http://examplesite.com/my-site#userid the following function is being called:

```
function my_page() {
    if($user->category == 0){
            drupal_goto('another-page'); //user gets redirected to http://examplesite.com/another-page#userid
    }else{
              //Corresponding code
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code so we can check.

Comment: tanx for the reply @Jayendra. I have edited my question likewise.

Comment: Unless you add a `fragment` to the `drupal_goto()` options there's no reason it would be added to the redirect URL. Have you confirmed this isn't a browser problem by trying a different machine/browser combination?

Comment: tanx for the reply @Clive.I have sure it is not a browser problem.I have checked it

Comment: I guess the next step is to force a new fragment to make sure the problem is definitely Drupal related, and not your server/client. If you use `drupal_goto('another-page', NULL, 'test');` instead, does the fragment change to `#test`, or does it stay as `#userid`?

Comment: the resultant link is get is http://examplesite.com/another-page?fragment=test#billing-edit

Comment: Er ok, that's definitely not a Drupal problem (unless `drupal_goto()` has been altered in some way). Drupal definitely won't append a random, unrelated string to the end of a redirected URL. Your client (browser or some machine setting), or the web server itself, must be causing that

Comment: is there some other way by which i could force it remove the part starting from the # symbol

Comment: Without knowing what's _adding_ it, I'm afraid I have no idea

Comment: anyway tanx @Clive :)